Wiring 2 generators and utilizing a subpanel
I would like to run a separate generator for my AC unit.  I have a sub panel with a main disconnect.  Is it legal to run a generator to each panel with proper interlock kit installed, and what are the requirements regarding neutral grounding. see drawing

Is the issue with running the AC off the main generator a lack of starting amps or a lack of running amps?

As I understand it you can theoretically only get 12000 watts continuous supply trout a 50 amp breaker, which is what is on the generator, so it is a matter of supply power. You can’t have two Generator feeds to the same panel can you?

Assuming the subpanel is on the main house and does not have its own ground bond, both generators need to be unbonded and both need ground and neutral attached separately to their respective panels.
If the A/C blower breaker is in the main panel and the sub generator can cope with both the compressor and blower, it would make sense to move the blower breaker to the subpanel.

If you also make your main panel into a sub, and install a small new main panel just to feed the TWO subs ... now the A/C is off the bigger panel and you can get a much smaller whole-house standby there, and use a cheapo portable for the A/C.
